# CheckedListBox event *after* CheckState changed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, checklistbox

I have a CheckedListBox control and a button in my WinForms project. It contains a list of items, and a max of 5 can be selected. I am using the `ItemCheck` event so each time the user checks or unchecks an item in the list a function is called which unchecks the last value if the total number of selected items was more than 5:

```
private void NumbersListItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    CheckedListBox checkedItems = (CheckedListBox)sender;
    if (checkedItems.CheckedItems.Count > 4)
    {
        e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
    }
    RefreshButtonState();
}
```

That way, the number of checked items will never exceed 5.

The button control is supposed to be disabled when the amount of checked items in my CheckedListBox is not 5 and enabled when it is. I am trying to call this function whenever there is a change in state:

```
private void RefreshButtonState()
{
    if (NumbersList.CheckedItems.Count == 5)
    {
         ModifyButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ModifyButton.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

However, the button stays disabled even when I have 5 items checked until I try to check a sixth, and vice versa - if I check 5 and then uncheck one, the button will become enabled. I know that this happens because the function is called *before* the actual change takes place.

Is there an event for CheckedListBox that gets called immediately after there is a state change, not when its about to change?

Comment: you should have your application be reactive, like https://reactiveui.net/docs/guidelines/platform/windows-forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need another event, just handle the `ItemChecked` and use the `e.NewValue` to get the count of the checked items *after* the `CheckState` is changed and not when the `ItemChecked` event is raised.

```cs
private void NumbersListItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    var s = sender as CheckedListBox;
    var count = s.CheckedIndices.Count + (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked ? 1 : -1);

    if (count > 5)
        e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;

    ModifyButton.Enabled = count >= 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ItemCheck event and check new state of the item which was checked. New state is in event arg as e.NewValue  . You can than check state in if(e.NewValue== CheckState.Check) and use it in your logic.